# Не передает файлы после смены пароль

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, password, filezilla

Использовал для подключения по SSH (для передачи файлов) FileZilla, все работало нормально, но вдруг мне нужно было сменить пароль, через PuTTy я подключился и сменил, смог повторно подключиться через PuTTY, т.е. пароль верный, при подключении через FileZilla у меня все подключает, найдены все каталоги, но как только я хочу добавить файлы, сразу же идет соеденения и выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка: Неудачная аутентификация.
>   Ошибка: Критическая ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу

P.S. Если сменить пароль обратно то все работает

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin криво напечатал, должно было быть SSH